# What determines the suite of Case Roles presented for assignment on the CIVICRM Webform Case Tab?

Tags: webform-civicrm

When I select a Case Type on the Case tab of the Webform, A suite of Case Roles are presented so a Contact on the CIVICRM tab can be mapped to them. Some of the Roles for the Case Type I selected are not presented. Is there a setting I need to use so all case roles are presented? The one that is missing is an organization contact type we added.

My site is Drupal 7.41, CiviCRM 4.6.10, and Webform CiviCRM Integration module 7.x-4.11.

Comment: It may be time to upgrade the webform-civicrm module; that's quite an old version.

Comment: Do you think the version would effect whether Webform CiviCRM Integration module would present custom contact types? In testing I determined that the built in Organization contact type worked as expected, but the Organization contact types we added did not.

Comment: It might. There have been some bugfixes along those lines.

Comment: I updated the version, but the issue remains. I will go ahead and submit an issue in Drupal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Come to find out that the role not being available to map was because the relationship name and label in the database did not match (i.e. name_b_a was "Third cousin once removed" but the label_b_a was "Distant cousin").  It seems like when the relationships were originally created we had the ability to set a different name and label - we're guessing this was in an earlier version of CiviCRM as currently the only thing you can add/edit directly in CIvi is the label.

Once the name field was revised to match the label, the role was available for selection in the Cases > case roles section.

Answer (score 2):

You can add roles to specific case types by going to Administer > CiviCase > Case Types, click to edit a given case type and you will see a section for "Roles" where you can add or remove roles as desired.

Roles are actually relationships, so you will need to ensure that you have all of the requisite relationships in place first by going to Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Relationship Types.

Hope this helps,
Tamar

Answer (score 0):

Now the bug has been fixed in Civi with the label v relationship name, it can still cause frustration - it is very easy to put the relationship in the wrong way around.  Even after all these years I still get caught out with Civi's Relationships.

So if you have created a relationship like 'Manager is' and 'Manager for' - if 'Manager is' does not appear on your webform, try adding 'Manager for' in the Case role and see if that shows up.  It can be a real gotcha depending on how you have set up the relationship.