# Assigning case role to contact in webform- not updating as expected

Tags: webform-civicrm, civicase, relationships

I've been trying to update a case webform so that form contacts are assigned to a given role.

I had expected that by creating roles under relationship types and then including the role in the case type settings in Civi, that the webform case tab would automatically update to offer the new roles for allocation.

It isn't doing this.
Options available in webform
[image: Case Roles in Wbform CiviCRM tab]

Options allocated in case type

[image: roles allocatd to case type]

Currently using civi 5.3.1 with webfromcivicrm 4.2.26

Have got this working on another site using civi 5.8.2 and webformcivicrm 4.2.24

Comment: I have tried clearing caches in civi, drupal and locally

Comment: Long shot, but are your relationships in sync with the contact types? And not the other way around?

Comment: I've set them to  link between individuals to try and keep things simple. I'll see if editting them makes a difference.

Comment: Narrowing down to subtype didn't affect system.

Answer (score 2):

Rephrased my search and found this question
[What determines the suite of Case Roles presented for assignment on the CIVICRM Webform Case Tab?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15227/what-determines-the-suite-of-case-roles-presented-for-assignment-on-the-civicrm)

1st answer talks about relationship names/labels not matching

Newer version of create relationship only allows user to set relationship label. name is auto generated

In this case "Other Professional is". The relationship was assigned the name "Other_Professional_is"

Editting the relationship name  to "Other Professional is", meant that it showed in the case roles.

Don't know if this level of tinkering will have knock on effects anywhere else.